# Ruby on Rails asking to put require and enable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, instagram

I'm not sure where to put require and enable?

I'm trying to use the instagram api, but it's telling me to put

```
require "sinatra"
require "instagram"

enable :sessions
```

in the sample application : https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

But I'm new to learning rails, so I'm just trying figure some bits out,

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you getting.. can you put the error details

Answer (score 0):

Thats for a sintatra app, not a rails app, for rails all I think you need to do is add it to your gemfile like so.

```
gem 'instagram'
```

If you still can't use it try adding :require, though I don't think you should have to.

```
gem 'instagram', :require => 'instagram'
```